# vim : Gundo error

Tags: python, vim

Since a while I have not use Gundo. Today, I have an error in my code and would like to go back on other "branch" using Gundo. But when I start Gundo, I have this error message : `Gundo requires Vim to be compiled with Python 2.4+` and Gundo is not working anymore. Can someone help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Gundo can't work without python 2.4. The workaround I found is to use undotree [git repos here](https://github.com/mbbill/undotree/). It is cool because it recognizes my gundo log, so that I don't loose anything.